# Meaning of higher-order derivations in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, intuition

In differential geometry, a derivation is defined to be an operator $D:C^{\infty}(M)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ that is linear and satisfies the first-order product rule:
$$ D(fg) = D(f)g + fD(g). $$

When I say "second-order derivations," I mean operators of the form $DD'$ where $D, D'$ are derivations.
In this case, $DD'$ is linear and satisfies 
$$ DD'(fg) = DD'(f)g + D(f)D'(g) + D'(f)D(g) + DD'(g). $$

**Questions.**

1. Are there any references that discuss these types of operators?
2. Does anyone have an intuitive/geometric interpretation of these operators? First-order derivations can be interpreted as vector fields (or tangent vectors if we're talking about pointwise derivations). Is there an extension of this type of reasoning?

---

**Edit.**

It looks like my definition has in general $DD'\ne D'D$. For example, in local coordinates let $D = \partial_{1}$ and $D' = x^{1}\partial_{2}$. Then 
$$ DD' = \partial_{1}(x^{1}\partial_{2}) = \partial_{2} + x^{1}\partial_{1}\partial_{2} \ne D'D. $$
I'm not sure what definition is appropriate, actually. The above is only my attempt.

Actually, the non-commutativity I just noted above is nothing new. We already know Lie brackets $[X, Y]$ can be nonzero. However, the more I play around, the more surprising nuances I seem to discover.

Comment: You can talk about higher-order tangent bundles (which, in the case of embedded submanifolds, can be interpreted—at least locally—in terms of osculating spaces). See Pohl, *Differential geometry of higher order*, Topology, 1 (1962), 169-211 or Shifrin, *The Osculatory Behavior of Surfaces in $\Bbb P^5$*, Pac. J. of Math, 123 (1986), 227-256.